# using await inside properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, c#-5.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call an async method from a getter or setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602244/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-a-getter-or-setter)

I'm trying to implement a property that'll use the Sqlite await inside it:

```
public int ID {
        get
        {
            if (_id != null)
            {
                return _id;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageName))
            {
                return -1;
            }
            var query = CurrentConnection.Table<Image>().Where(i => i.ImageName == ImageName);
            var result = await query.ToListAsync();
            ...other code
```

However, since a property is not set to await(tried that, doesn't work), I can't use await inside a property.

Any way to get around this besides using a method instead of a property?

Comment: Simply use the synchronous version.

Comment: you have a recursion bug. should be `if(_id != null) return _id;` not `ID`

Comment: I would expect properties to be small and fast. Anything involving waiting should go in a method if you ask me. Just saying ...

Comment: If you have a `Task<T>` named `blah`, you can call `blah.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. -- But that will block on the current thread --
 and unless it's super fast code you're awaiting, I would strongly consider alternative options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No - there's no such thing as an async property. Even if you *could* declare an async property, it would have to be declared as having a return value of `Task<int>` rather than `int`... otherwise what would you want to return when you hit an `await` expression?

I would *strongly* suggest a `GetIdAsync` method here, assuming you definitely want async behaviour.

Comment: Also note that if it's a property of type `Task<int>` it would make setters *really* weird.

Comment: Since async/await can't be used in conjunction with yield return blocks, a sensible compromise would have been manually implementing IEnumerator<Task<T>>, where the Current property is async. This rule that async can't be used on properties is a stylistic constraint that precludes this useful pattern. The only solution now is to expose *internal* iteration details to clients so they can perform the iteration manually. Horrible.

Answer (score 11):

There is no *technical* reason that `async` properties are not allowed in C#. It was a purposeful design decision, because "asynchronous properties" is an oxymoron.

Properties should return current values; they should not be kicking off background operations.

Usually, when someone wants an "asynchronous property", what they really want is one of these:

1. An asynchronous method that returns a value. In this case, change the property to an `async` method.
2. A value that can be used in data-binding but must be calculated/retrieved asynchronously. In this case, either use an `async` factory method for the containing object or use an `async InitAsync()` method. The data-bound value will be `default(T)` until the value is calculated/retrieved.
3. A value that is expensive to create, but should be cached for future use. In this case, use `AsyncLazy` [from my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html) or [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/). This will give you an `await`able property.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use a property Getter for anything besides just returning a variable value anyway.

Calling code often makes performance-wise assumptions of what to expect when calling your classes.

**Rule of thumb:**

- **Properties** imply a very **fast** return of a value
- **Methods** imply more or less **lengthy operations**

Therefore it is strongly recommended not to put any lengthy logic into a getter. Use methods instead.

**Microsofts's Rico Mariany** gives a very detailed article about it here: [Performance Guidelines for Properties](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2011/12/19/performance-guidelines-for-properties.aspx)

Comment: Service fabric has async dictionaries to get state objects -- it's very fast, and they do it all over the damn place in code samples. -- It seems like 90% of the time it's a very very cheap operation. -- But it's so much more code to write than just grabbing a property. -- There needs to be a solution to that. :(

Comment: @BrainSlugs83: Do I understand correctly that you are downvoting me because you do not like Microsoft's implementation of reliable collection...?

Answer (score 0):

If you use await, you are turning the rest of the method into a callback, which means you cannot return an int. You would need to return an Task<int>. Currently there is also no support for using await in a property, you'd need to convert the property into a "get" method returning the Task<int>.

If you want to return the int directly, instead of doing await *awaitable*, use *awaitable*.Result. This will cause the asyncronous action to resolve syncronously, allowing you to return the concrete result directly.

Comment: However performing a database query inside of a property getter is generally considered a poor idea.  Property getters should be fast and simple.

Comment: It depends on what the property's main purpose is. If the object is a DbLoggedInUser and the property is FirstName, then it would seem reasonable for the property to perform a database query in the background. However you are right that in general properties should be simple and not be able to fail.

Comment: It would never seem reasonable to do a database query in the background of a property's getter. -- That's just wrong. -- That *needs* to be a method call.