# Lazy load properties with Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, lazy-loading

I've learned to lazy load properties in my repository. Now I'd like to do that, but I also need to load something from a web page (using Httpclient) which means my property will be async.

```
public async Task<List<NewsModel>> News
{
    get
    {
        if (_news == null)
        {
            CacheProvider cache = new CacheProvider();
            object cachedNews = cache.Get("news");

            if (cachedNews == null)
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                // await HttpResponse
            }

        }
        return _news;
    }

    set
    {
        _news = value;
    }
}
```

However, visual studio is telling me that

> *"The modifier async is not valid for this item"*

while highlighting the word "News" in the first line.

Is it possible to do this? Or do I have to write a separate method?

Comment: I take it that you've got the using statement for System.Threading.Tasks? Also, which .NET framework is this targeting? Is it Silverlight? -- Never mind, just saw that this is a property. You'll want to convert this into methods.

Comment: It seems to me like the property `News` would intuitively have the type `List<NewsModel>`, the `Task<>` decoration doesn't seem natural here. Why do you feel that you need to expose the `Task<>` nature?

Comment: @AndrewCoonce Actually, if he wants to write an async *method*, he would definitely have to write it as returning a task.

Comment: Because visual studio told me to do that :( First time I deal with async in C#.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes, but this isn't a method... this is a property. I guess my concern is that the end-user isn't expecting side-effects, asynchronous operation, etc... they're expecting an enumeration of news items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [caching the result from a \[n async\] factory method iff it doesn't throw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872588/caching-the-result-from-a-n-async-factory-method-iff-it-doesnt-throw)

Comment: Related: [Enforce an async method to be called once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, properties with side-effects are usually not all that good.

In this case, simply *reading* this property would kick off a thread, some network traffic, and some processing on a remote server.

This should be a method, not a property.

Secondly, the compiler is right, properties are not allowed to be asynchronous. Now, you can definitely *write* a property that returns an asynchronous task, but you're not allowed to use the `async` keyword. Basically just take away the `async` keyword from the property declaration.

But the fact that `async` is not legal on properties is another clue that you should write a method, not a property.

<strike>**Note** The `async` keyword is not actually required in the code you've posted, since you're not actually using the `await` keyword in there. As such, you can simply remove the `async` keyword altogether, since it is not required. In fact, if you were to change this over to a method, the compiler will tell you that it is unnecessary since you're not using `await`.</strike> *(Removed after OP edited the question.)*

Comment: oh wait! I am using await! httpclient will use await as the guy here did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp

Comment: If I remove the 'await' I have to wrap HttpResponseMessage in a task - which means I have to write an 'await' somewhere in the code...

Comment: Well, you still cannot write properties using `async`, so `await` has to go as well.

Comment: So should I delete the ENTIRE property and write it as a method instead? Many thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: Yes. That is what you should do.

Comment: Ok, last question: should then the method be "async" or return a "Task<>"? What do you advise?

Comment: The op's code does not start another thread. Also, an `async` method is not a good semantic match either because the op only wishes the network request to happen once.

Comment: _"First of all, properties with side-effects are usually not all that good"_ - well no, that's how **proxy classes** with **on-demand/lazy-load** loading work such as in _ORMs_

Comment: I agree with "properties with side-effects are usually not all that good" but I don't think it is applicable here. Properties should not change the logical state of the system. I don't think loading data is a side-effect. Querying a property is asking a question. Working to answer the question is an expected effect.

Answer (score 14):

Asynchronous properties are not supported. I describe a [number of workarounds](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) on my blog.

In your case, it sounds like [asynchronous lazy initialization](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html) would be a good solution (also described on my blog).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Lazy property that returns a Task:

```
class MyClass
{
    readonly Lazy<Task<string>> _text;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _text = new Lazy<Task<string>>(async () =>
        {
            //... await something
            return "Hello!"
        });
    }
 
    async Task DoSomething()
    {
       var text = await _text.Value;
       //...
    }
}
```

**Update:** Be aware that `Lazy` uses `Monitor.Enter` internally, so accessing it from many threads simultaneously can cause a denial of service. I have made a basic implementation of Lazy using `SemaphoreSlim`, which will leave threads available while waiting for the value. See my gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ArtemAvramenko/1c9d4d90a05dcbbe24d0c64848f48a50)

Comment: IMHO this make Lazy useless, in this case Lazy will only initialize task, which most of the cases is not what you want

Answer (score 1):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602244/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-a-getter-or-setter) is related.

In short - async properties are not supported.