# Enforce an async method to be called once

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Say I have a class that needs to perform some async initialization using an InitializeAsync() method.
I want to make sure that the initialization is performed only once. If another thread calls this method while the initalization is already in progress, it will "await" until the first call returns.

I was thinking about the following imlementation (using SemaphoreSlim).
Is there a better/simpler approach?

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim mSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private bool mIsInitialized;

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        if (!mIsInitialized)
        {
            await mSemaphore.WaitAsync();

            if (!mIsInitialized)
            {
                await DoStuffOnlyOnceAsync();
                mIsInitialized = true;
            }

            mSemaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    private Task DoStuffOnlyOnceAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Since I'm using DI and this service will be injected, consuming it as a "Lazy" resource or using an async factory won't work for me (although it could be great in other use cases).
Thus, the async initialization should be encapsulated within the class and transparent to the `IMyService` consumers.

The idea of wrapping the initialization code in a "dummy" `AsyncLazy<>` object will do the job, although it feels a bit unnatural to me.

Comment: Use a `Lazy` whose initialization method does what you want. This ensures that the initialization method is only called once

Comment: If you go with this solution be sure to call `Release` in a finally block.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this code btw? Or was this simply about simplifying the code? Basically I can't use `Lazy` in my code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd go with [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asynclazyt/) (slightly modified version):

```
public class AsyncLazy<T> : Lazy<Task<T>> 
{ 
    public AsyncLazy(Func<T> valueFactory) : 
        base(() => Task.Run(valueFactory)) { }

    public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory) : 
        base(() => Task.Run(() => taskFactory())) { } 

    public TaskAwaiter<T> GetAwaiter() { return Value.GetAwaiter(); } 
}
```

And consume it like this:

```
private AsyncLazy<bool> asyncLazy = new AsyncLazy<bool>(async () =>
                                    { 
                                        await DoStuffOnlyOnceAsync()
                                        return true;
                                    });
```

Note i'm using `bool` simply because you have no return type from `DoStuffOnlyOnceAsync`.

**Edit:**

Stephan Cleary (of course) also has an implementation of this [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html).

Comment: That's Stephen Toub's [AsyncLazy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/15/10116210.aspx)  implementation for .NET 4.0. He describes why you need to do this instead of just calling the asynchronous method during initialization.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know. This is copied from his post in the PFX team. I've added the link :)

Comment: Stephen Cleary updates this for .NET 4.5 and does away with unwrapping [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos They're partically the same, only update with `Task.Run` instead. I've updated the code.

Comment: Why is it using Task.Run?

Comment: @Rookian because otherwise it would be possible for multiple worker threads to be blocked during the execution of the `valueFactory`. With the `Task.Run` only one thread can be blocked, which will be the `ThreadPool` thread that is used by the `Task.Run`. No thread that calls `await asyncLazy;` is gonna get blocked.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Use [Stephen Cleary's `AsyncLazy`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/asynchronous-lazy-initialization.html) (available on the [`AsyncEx` nuget](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx)):

```
private static readonly AsyncLazy<MyResource> myResource = new AsyncLazy<MyResource>(
    async () => 
    { 
        var ret = new MyResource(); 
        await ret.InitAsync(); 
        return ret; 
    }
);

public async Task UseResource()
{
    MyResource resource = await myResource;
    // ...
}
```

Or the [visual studio SDK's `AsyncLazy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asynclazy-1) if you prefer a Microsoft implementation.

Answer (score 6):

I have a [blog post that covers a few different options for doing "asynchronous constructors"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Normally, I prefer asynchronous factory methods, because I think they're simpler and a bit safer:

```
public class MyService
{
  private MyService() { }

  public static async Task<MyService> CreateAsync()
  {
    var result = new MyService();
    result.Value = await ...;
    return result;
  }
}
```

`AsyncLazy<T>` is a perfectly good way of defining a shared asynchronous resource (and may be a better conceptual match for a "service", depending on how it is used). The one advantage of the async factory method approach is that it's not possible to create an uninitialized version of `MyService`.

Comment: +1, factory methods are definitely the way to go in this scenario.  I'd recommend making the factory non static so it can be easily mocked and dependency injected.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Toub's [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asynclazyt/) implementation, based on a `Lazy<Task<T>>`, is pretty nice and concise, but there are a few things that are not entirely to my liking:

1. In case the asynchronous operation fails, the error is cached, and will be propagated to all future awaiters of the `AsyncLazy<T>` instance. There is no way to un-cache the cached `Task`, so that the asynchronous operation can be retried. This makes the `AsyncLazy<T>` practically unusable for the purpose of implementing a caching system, for example.
2. The asynchronous delegate is invoked on the `ThreadPool`. There is no way to invoke it on the calling thread.
3. If we try to solve the previous problem by invoking the `taskFactory` delegate directly instead of wrapping it in `Task.Factory.StartNew`, then in the unfortunate case that the delegate blocks the calling thread for a significant amount of time, all threads that will `await` the `AsyncLazy<T>` instance will get blocked until the completion of the delegate. This is a direct consequence of how the [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) type works. This type was never designed for supporting asynchronous operations in any way.
4. The `Lazy<Task<T>>` combination generates [warnings](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD011.md) in the latest version of the Visual Studio 2019 (16.8.2). It seems that this combination [can produce deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517656/lazytaskt-with-asynchronous-initialization) in some scenarios.

The first issue has been addressed by Stephen Cleary's `AsyncLazy<T>` [implementation](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncLazy.cs) (part of the [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library), that accepts a `RetryOnFailure` flag in its constructor. The second issue has also been addressed by the same implementation (`ExecuteOnCallingThread` flag). AFAIK the third and the fourth issues have not been addressed.

Below is an attempt to address all of these issues. This implementation instead of being based on a `Lazy<Task<T>>`, it is based on a transient nested task (`Task<Task<T>>`).

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the result of an asynchronous operation that is invoked lazily
/// on demand, with the option to retry it as many times as needed until it
/// succeeds, while enforcing a non-overlapping execution policy.
/// </summary>
public class AsyncLazy<TResult>
{
    private Func<Task<TResult>> _taskFactory;
    private readonly bool _retryOnFailure;
    private Task<TResult> _task;

    public AsyncLazy(Func<Task<TResult>> taskFactory, bool retryOnFailure = false)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(taskFactory);
        _taskFactory = taskFactory;
        _retryOnFailure = retryOnFailure;
    }

    public Task<TResult> Task
    {
        get
        {
            Task<TResult> capturedTask = Volatile.Read(ref _task);
            if (capturedTask is not null) return capturedTask;

            Task<Task<TResult>> newTaskTask = new(_taskFactory);
            Task<TResult> newTask = null;
            newTask = newTaskTask.Unwrap().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully || !_retryOnFailure)
                {
                    _taskFactory = null; // No longer needed (let it get recycled)
                    return task;
                }
                // Discard the stored _task, to trigger a retry later.
                Task<TResult> original = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _task, null);
                Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(original, newTask));
                return task;
            }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
            capturedTask = Interlocked
                .CompareExchange(ref _task, newTask, null) ?? newTask;
            if (ReferenceEquals(capturedTask, newTask))
                newTaskTask.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler.Default);
            return capturedTask;
        }
    }

    public TaskAwaiter<TResult> GetAwaiter() => this.Task.GetAwaiter();

    public ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<TResult> ConfigureAwait(
        bool continueOnCapturedContext)
        => this.Task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext);
}
```

Usage example:

```
AsyncLazy<string> lazyOperation = new(async () =>
{
    return await _httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://stackoverflow.com");
}, retryOnFailure: true);

//... (here the operation has not started yet)

string html = await lazyOperation;
```

The `taskFactory` delegate is invoked on the calling thread (the thread that calls the `await lazyOperation` in the example above). If you prefer to invoke it on the `ThreadPool`, you can either change the implementation and replace the [`RunSynchronously`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.runsynchronously) with the [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) method, or wrap the `taskFactory` in `Task.Run` (`lazyOperation = new(() => Task.Run(async () =>` in the example above). Normally an asynchronous delegate is expected to return quickly, so invoking it on the calling thread shouldn't be a problem. As a bonus it opens the possibility of interacting with thread-affine components, like UI controls, from inside the delegate.

This implementation propagates all the exceptions that might be thrown by the `taskFactory` delegate, not just the first one. This might be important in a few cases, like when the delegate returns directly a [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) task. To do this first store the `AsyncLazy<T>.Task` in a variable, then `await` the variable, and finally in the `catch` block inspect the [`Exception.InnerExceptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions) property of the variable.

An online demonstration of the `AsyncLazy<T>` class can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3pPNh). It demonstrates the behavior of the class when used by multiple concurrent workers, and the `taskFactory` fails.

**Improvement:** It is possible to implement a more memory-efficient version of the `AsyncLazy<TResult>`, by making the `retryOnFailure` behavior mandatory instead of optional. In this case we could simply cache an unwrapped `TResult` value, instead of caching a fully fledged `Task<TResult>`. The optimized version can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/theodorzoulias/778c54ec77112af50ea087811607ffba).