# Force C# async tasks to be lazy?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-core

I have a situation where I have an object tree created by a special factory. This is somewhat similar to a DI container, but not quite.

Creation of objects always happens via constructor, and the objects are immutable.

Some parts of the object tree may not be needed in a given execution and should be created lazily. So the constructor argument should be something that is just a factory for on-demand creation. This looks like a job for `Lazy`.

However, object creation may need to access slow resources and is thus always async. (The object factory's creation function returns a `Task`.) This means that the creation function for the `Lazy` would need to be async, and thus the injected type needs to be `Lazy<Task<Foo>>`.

But I'd rather not have the double wrapping. I wonder if it is possible to force a `Task` to be lazy, i.e. to create a `Task` that is guaranteed to not execute until it is awaited. As I understand it, a `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` may start executing at any time (e.g. if a thread from the pool is idle), even if nothing is waiting for it.

```
public class SomePart
{
  // Factory should create OtherPart immediately, but SlowPart
  // creation should not run until and unless someone actually
  // awaits the task.
  public SomePart(OtherPart eagerPart, Task<SlowPart> lazyPart)
  {
    EagerPart = eagerPart;
    LazyPart = lazyPart;
  }

  public OtherPart EagerPart {get;}
  public Task<SlowPart> LazyPart {get;}
}
```

Comment: This helpful? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/15/asynclazyt/

Comment: @DavidG Thanks, I've read this article before. This would be the workaround I would use if I can't make a plain `Task` lazy, but I'm still hoping for a way to do that.

Comment: Await will not start a task for you if it's not already started, so you cannot "create a Task that is guaranteed to not execute until it is awaited" (unless you start it yourself somewhen before await happens).

Comment: I don't mind `Lazy<Task<T>>` myself, but I do have a convenience [`AsyncLazy<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenClearyArchive/AsyncEx.Coordination/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncLazy.cs) in my [AsyncEx library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/).

Comment: Related: [Enforce an async method to be called once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why you want to avoid using `Lazy<Task<>>,`, but if it's just for keeping the API easier to use, as this is a property, you could do it with a backing field:

```
public class SomePart
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<SlowPart>> _lazyPart;

    public SomePart(OtherPart eagerPart, Func<Task<SlowPart>> lazyPartFactory)
    {
        _lazyPart = new Lazy<Task<SlowPart>>(lazyPartFactory);
        EagerPart = eagerPart;
    }

    OtherPart EagerPart { get; }
    Task<SlowPart> LazyPart => _lazyPart.Value;
}
```

That way, the usage is as if it were just a task, but the initialisation is lazy and will only incur the work if needed.

Answer (score 7):

@Max' answer is good but I'd like to add the version which is built on top of Stephen Toub' article mentioned in comments:

```
public class SomePart: Lazy<Task<SlowPart>>
{
    public SomePart(OtherPart eagerPart, Func<Task<SlowPart>> lazyPartFactory)
        : base(() => Task.Run(lazyPartFactory))
    {
        EagerPart = eagerPart;
    }

    public OtherPart EagerPart { get; }
    public TaskAwaiter<SlowPart> GetAwaiter() => Value.GetAwaiter();
}
```

1. SomePart's explicitly inherited from `Lazy<Task<>>` so it's clear that it's *lazy* and *asyncronous*.
2. Calling base constructor wraps `lazyPartFactory` to `Task.Run` to avoid long block if that factory needs some cpu-heavy work before real async part. If it's not your case, just change it to `base(lazyPartFactory)`
3. SlowPart is accessible through TaskAwaiter. So SomePart' public interface is:

   - `var eagerValue = somePart.EagerPart;`
   - `var slowValue = await somePart;`

Comment: Isn't maybe better @Max answer because use composition instead of inheritance? IsValueCreated could be misinterpreted in the API context, no?

Comment: yeah, totally agree

Answer (score 0):

Declaration:

```
private Lazy<Task<ServerResult>> _lazyServerResult;`


ctor()
{
    _lazyServerResult = new Lazy<Task<ServerResult>>(async () => await 
        GetServerResultAsync())
}
```

Usage:

```
ServerResult result = await _lazyServerResult.Value;
```

Comment: This is not answer for current issue, but i think this answer help most of all users? so +1

Answer (score -1):

Using the constructor for `Task` make the task lazy a.k.a not running until you say it to run, so you could do something like this:

```
public class TestLazyTask
{
    private Task<int> lazyPart;

    public TestLazyTask(Task<int> lazyPart)
    {
        this.lazyPart = lazyPart;
    }

    public Task<int> LazyPart
    {
        get
        {
            // You have to start it manually at some point, this is the naive way to do it
            this.lazyPart.Start();
            return this.lazyPart;
        }
    }
}


public static async void Test()
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("Creating task");
    var lazyTask = new Task<int>(() =>
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Task run");
        return 0;
    });
    var taskWrapper = new TestLazyTask(lazyTask);
    Trace.TraceInformation("Calling await on task");
    await taskWrapper.LazyPart;
}
```

Result:

```
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Creating task
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Calling await on task
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Task run
```

**However** I strongly recommend you to use [Rx.NET](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) and `IObservable` as in your case you will get way less troubles for handling less naive cases to start your task at the right moment. 
Also it makes the code a bit cleaner in my opinion

```
public class TestLazyObservable
{
    public TestLazyObservable(IObservable<int> lazyPart)
    {
        this.LazyPart = lazyPart;
    }

    public IObservable<int> LazyPart { get; }
}


public static async void TestObservable()
{
    Trace.TraceInformation("Creating observable");
    // From async to demonstrate the Task compatibility of observables
    var lazyTask = Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Observable run");
        return 0;
    }));

    var taskWrapper = new TestLazyObservable(lazyTask);
    Trace.TraceInformation("Calling await on observable");
    await taskWrapper.LazyPart;
}
```

Result:

```
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Creating observable
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Calling await on observable
SandBox.exe Information: 0 : Observable run
```

To be more clear: The `Observable` here handle when to start the task, it is Lazy by default and will run the task everytime it is subscribed (here subscribe is used by the awaiter that enable the use of the `await` keyword).

You could, if you need to, make the task run only once every minute (or ever) and having its result published across all subscribers to save performance for instance, like in a real world app, all of this and many more is handled by observables.

Comment: `I strongly recommend you to use Rx.NET and IObservable`
- that's what I call an overkill for this particular problem. Reactiveness is cool but I'd keep it for another time

Comment: It is not overkill if you don't overlook all the amount of particular problems you have to handle on daily basis in a real world app. You can argue this is like the good old "use jquery" thing, and it is somehow, but I really felt like OP scenario was relevant to this. Plus I did answer his question without Observables, I mentioned it as something he should use.

Comment: that's why it's better to not create even more problems and raise entropy by chosing improper tools, imho

Comment: It is the most proper tool to do lazy async processing I can think of.
It do not require special boilerplate code and is adaptive to the use case. I think, and it is my opinion, that in this case it will save more troubles than it creates compared to solving the issue with a quick workaround

Comment: Ok, maybe I just don't understand Rx quite right but I thought it is mostrly to deal with push-based asyncronous streams of events/objects/etc.