# Deadlock on Async lazy with PublicationOnly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, task-parallel-library

Assume the following code

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        Lazy<TimeSpan> lm = new Lazy<TimeSpan>(GetDataAsync1, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2", lm.Value.ToString() };
    }

    private TimeSpan GetDataAsync1()
    {

        return GetTS().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

    // I Cant change this method, and what is inside it...
    private async Task<TimeSpan> GetTS()
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com/");
        }

        sw.Stop();
        return sw.Elapsed;
    }
}
```

The point is that I am getting some data from remote server, and want to cache that for later use. As remote server may fail in a given point, I dont want to cache exception, but only success result... So keeping than awaiting the value will not work for me

```
// Cant use this, because this caches failed exception as well
Lazy<Task...> lz = ...
await lz.Value
```

But above snipped, as expected produce a deadlock, given that I cant change GetTS, is it possible to force Lazy work with my logic?

Comment: What do you want to do if you don't have a cached value when one is fetched, and you try to fetch one from the server but that fails? What should you return?

Comment: This GetTS().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult() cries deadlock!

Comment: when fails, I want to return exception, and on the next request try again... LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly - without async gives this functionality out of the box...

Comment: @Nick, I understand, If I move ConfigureAwait into GetTS, it will solve the problem... but I cant...

Comment: So, have some logic which checks the cached `Task`. If it is complete and contains an exception, then retry the request and return the new in-progress `Task`

Comment: Don't ever call `GetResult()` on a `Task`. Instead, use `await` on it.

Comment: @Alejandro, I know that, but try to do await on Lazy ;)

Comment: @canton7, in theory yes, than I dont need lazy right?

Comment: Correct, but you'll need your own locking of course

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan You likely need to change the `Lazy<TimeSpan>` to `Lazy<Task<TimeSpan>>` instead, where the implementing method can be async there. Or as an alternative, change `GetTS` to be sync instead.

Comment: Ok Guys, decided to move away from Lazy... async/await is nice, but it force some logic in whole application... thanks all for help

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Enforce an async method to be called once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once). It includes an implementation that doesn't use the `Lazy<T>` class.

Comment: I found AsyncLazy useful, but it still does not solve issue non caching exceptions... however I have decided to go with it ... I found this discussion, at the latest post @StephenCleary suggested a way to solve that issue, however dont want to go so deep at this point. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27510

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem actually has nothing to do with `Lazy<T>`. The deadlock is because it's [blocking on asynchronous code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

In this code:

```
private TimeSpan GetDataAsync1()
{
  return GetTS().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

the `ConfigureAwait(false)` does nothing. `ConfigureAwait` configures *awaits*, not *tasks*, and there is no `await` there.

The best option is to go [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). If exceptions are a concern, you can use [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) and pass `AsyncLazyFlags.RetryOnFailure`.

If you can't go `async` all the way, the next best option would be to go synchronous all the way. If you can't do either of these, then you'll have to choose a [sync-over-async hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development); be aware that there is no hack that works in all situations.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary, this really make sense. Didnt know about AsyncLazyFlags.RetryOnFailure, that is exactly what I am asking. I understand that the problem is not in Lazy side, but that not all FCL classes are easy suitable to async staff

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found no easy way of doing this, but the feature request discussion in .net github gives a complete picture of current situation

[GitHub: Add async support to System.Lazy](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27510)

Actually 5th point from last @StephenCleary answers my question for exception caching

> 5. Resetting on exceptions is also an important use case. I've addressed
>    this by adding another async lazy flag that will reset the
>    AsyncLazy to an uninitialized state if an exception is thrown from
>    the delegate. All existing accessors see the exception, but the next
>    accessor will retry the delegate.