# What's the best way to Asyncronously load properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I'm using c# .net core 5 Blazer WebService.

I have a service that has a list of Thing as a property.

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public HashSet<Thing> Things {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to load the Things from disk, so I cache them privately in the service

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private HashSet<Thing> _things
    public HashSet<Thing> Things => _things : LoadThings();
}
```

But LoadThings() accesses the disk so I want that IO to run asynchronously and await it. But now LoadThings() needs to be async, and I can't do:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private HashSet<Thing> _things
    public HashSet<Thing> Things => _things : await LoadThings();
}
```

And I get why; the async chain is lost.

So my question is this: What's the best way to get _things but await an async IO if _things is null?

Comment: There are no asynchronous properties. Replace the property with a method that either returns the cached data or retrieves fresh data

Comment: If you want to lazily initialize the data instead of actually cache them with expiration you could check [AsyncLazy](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLazy)

Comment: `But LoadThings() accesses the disk so I want that IO to run asynchronously` depending on what you're doing (in `LoadThings`), keep in mind this may not be the way to go and still may run synchronous; just a thought.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Enforce an async method to be called once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once)

Answer (score 1):

When you say "cache" I'm assuming that you're referring to something that just loads and re-uses them vs "cache" with an expiration. That seems to match your existing code.

In that case you could do this:

```cs
    public class Service : IService
    {
        private Lazy<Task<HashSet<Thing>>> _things;

        public Service()
        {
            _things = new Lazy<Task<HashSet<Thing>>>(LoadThings);
        }

        public async Task MethodThatNeedsThings()
        {
            var things = await _things.Value;
            // Now you've got things and you can use them.
        }

        private async Task<HashSet<Thing>> LoadThings()
        {
            // This method asynchronously loads your things.
        }
    }
```

The things get asynchronously loaded the first time you need them, and after that they're available on subsequent calls.

Comment: I was under the impression that doing complicated stuff like that in the constructor was generally a bad idea. This looks good to me, but what happens here is the IO throws an error?

Comment: @Tod Nothing complex is happening in the constructor. `LoadThings` is lazily evaluated when `_things.Value` is first accessed, so any exceptions would be thrown when `MethodThatNeedsThings` is invoked.