# Wrap async Task function call in a Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have an asynchronous function, for simplicity, let's have it be this:

```
static async Task TestTask(object? _)
{
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    await Task.Delay(500);
    Console.WriteLine("3");
}
```

I want to encapsulate the execution of this function in a `Task` that I can start at some later point or somewhere in code that has no direct knowledge of this function. I've been trying a few ways to do this encapsulation, including:

```
static Task GetTask1() =>
    new(async () => await TestTask(null));

static Task GetTask2() =>
    new(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(async _ => await TestTask(null), null, 
        TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent));

static Task GetTask3() => 
    new(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(TestTask, null, 
        TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent));
```

When used in a program, like the following example, the function starts but is considered 'complete' at the function's first `await`:

```
Console.WriteLine("1");

// Create the task to hold on to for later.
Task toStart = GetTask3();
// Later (or elsewhere), start the task.
toStart.Start();

await Task.WhenAll(toStart);
Console.WriteLine("4");
```

This results in only 1, 2, and 4 being output to the console.

I think I understand why `GetTask1` and `GetTask2` aren't working (due to the nested `async` execution), but it seems like `GetTask3` should work by attaching the running task to the parent task that is later started.

Why would this not work and what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: _"but it seems like GetTask3 should work"_ - none of them will, Task<T> ctors are not task-aware, they accept `Func<T>` not `Func<Task>` so they will not await for the inner task completion, they will just start it and that's it. You are returning just `Task` in your `Get..` methods effectively discarding the inner task. Change the first one to `static Task<Task> GetTask1() => new(async () => await TestTask(null));` and then `await await toStart;` (though it is a bit pointless - just use `Func<Task>`). Added a second dup with similar problem.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the question was closed so I decided to add it as a comment.

Comment: The duplicate question is generally similar enough. It doesn't quite match my specific case, but on the whole it agrees with both Guru Stron and jhmckimm (answer below), which is that I'll have to work around to use either a Task<Task> or Func<Task>. Thanks everyone!

Comment: As a side note, the `Task.Factory.StartNew` usage inside the question violates the [CA2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) guideline about not creating tasks without passing a `TaskScheduler`.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite simply use `Func<Task>` to wrap it:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = GetSomeTask();
        
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        
        await task.Invoke();
        
        Console.WriteLine("4");
    }
   
    private static Func<Task> GetSomeTask()
    {
        return MyMethod;
    }
    
    private static async Task MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        
        await Task.Delay(500);
        
        Console.WriteLine("3");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: What if I need the return type to be a Task? More specifically, and my example simplified away from this, my Task provider is implementing an interface that specifies that the return type be a Task.

Comment: Are you able to share the full signature of the method you need to implement?

Comment: It looks something like:
public Task[] GetSetupStages()
{
    return new Task[]
    {
        new(() =>
        {
            // First stage syncronous stuff.
        }),
        new(async () => await SomeAsyncTask()),
        new(async () => await OtherAsyncTask()),
        new(() =>
        {
            // Last stage syncronous stuff.
        })
    };
}
So, it's moderately more complicated than the question example, which is narrowed down to what was causing me problems.

Comment: Ah, yikes, I see. If it really is expecting tasks that it will start itself later, then it feels like an abuse of the Task system to expect an array of Tasks and not an array of delegates (which return tasks). Are you sure that you're not supposed to be starting the tasks yourself in this method?

Comment: Yea, the tasks provided are reorganized with the setup tasks provided by other instances of similar implementations, such that all of the first stage tasks are performed together, then all the second stages tasks, and so on.

Comment: In that case I would checked out the answers outlined in the close message of this question. :)

Comment: It does appear I'll have to work around this in some fashion, either with Task<Task> or Func<Task>. Thanks!

Comment: @LucasStertz personally I still would switch from tasks to `Func<Task>` but this seems to be a rare case when you might want to consider looking into `ContinueWith` shenanigans (though still not sure that it will be helpful here without seeing the full code).

Comment: @GuruStron I think I will work with Func<Task>. The way the Tasks are re-organized later would be more complicated with ContinueWith (per how I picture using it). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @LucasStertz the `Task<Task>` is more powerful than the `Func<Task>`, because it gives you immediately a `Task` that you can pass to other methods. It can be used for implementing an [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340177/enforce-an-async-method-to-be-called-once/65714904#65714904) for example. On the other hand the `Func<Task>` is simpler and more lightweight. So if you don't need immediately a representation of the deferred asynchronous operation, the `Func<Task>` is the way to go.