# How to call an aync method in Setter on Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In my setter method of a property which bounds to UI, I need to call an async method.

```
public string Property
{
   set {
        _property = value;

        AMethodAsync();
   }
}
```

But I am getting a compiler warning saying 'execution of this call method continues before the call is complete'.

How can I fix this compiler warning?

I read this thread, 
[How to call an async method from a getter or setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602244/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-a-getter-or-setter)
but the Dispatcher is not available on Windows phone.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could wrap the call (plus the `.Wait()` call) into a function and stick it in the `ThreadPool` for execution.

Comment: I agree with @PhilipPittle. You should to use System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate(object state) { AMethodAsync(); });

Comment: Could you explain why you want to invoke the async method in the property? Based on the purpose there are several ways to achieve a goal without calling the async method in the setter. The compiler warning is not a problem at all if you know what you are doing, though such calls are actually a bad practice.

Comment: I need to call async method in order to relate the change in my property (in Setter of the property) to server.

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted your question as simply *how to disable a warning*. You can temporarily disable this particular warning in this property like this:

```
#pragma warning disable 4014
public string Property
{
    set
    {
        _property = value;
        AMethodAsync();
    }
}
#pragma warning restore 4014
```

This is useful to silence the warning inside a section of code. Keep in mind, all this does is stops the compiler from generating the warning. Usually if you do this, it means you have a good reason for ignoring the warning in the first place.

---

Another way to silence the warning is to assign the task object to a variable like this:

```
public string Property
{
    set
    {
        _property = value;
        var task = AMethodAsync();
    }
}
```