# UWP: Setting the image.source from FilePath in the 'get; & set;'

Tags: get, filepath, uwp, bitmapimage, isolatedstoragefile

Each image in the collection has a serialized File Path. When loading the collection I need the image to load from the File Path. The code below will not work because IsolatedStorageFileStream isn't compatible with the IRandomAccessStream used for to image.SetSource().

```
public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            if (FilePath == null) return null;

            IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());

            image.SetSource(stream);

            return image;
        }
    }
```

Is there alternative code to accomplish this?

Comment: one way is implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: If you can post the code as an answer I'll mark it as a right answer if the code works.

Comment: To do not repeat the answer take a look to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29407143/4725755

Comment: @TerryBennett Please also note the comments on Juan's answer, e.g. "be very skeptical of following this advice...". Using `async void` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use the [WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.AsRandomAccessStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.windowsruntimestreamextensions.asrandomaccessstream(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
using System.IO;
...

using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(
    FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
    IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
{
    await image.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
}
```

When I tested this `SetSource` was blocking the application, so I used `SetSourceAsync`.

---

You could perhaps also directly access the Isolated Storage folder like this:

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
    FilePath, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
{
    await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
```