# Await an async function from setter property

Tags: c#, windows, async-await

I need to await to an async function from a property setter method.

```
public String testFunc()
{
get
{

}
set
{
    //Await Call to the async func <asyncFunc()>

}
}
```

I understand we should not make async properties, so what is the optimal way to do this.

Comment: Show this post, i think this is your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602244/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-a-getter-or-setter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call an async method from a getter or setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602244/how-to-call-an-async-method-from-a-getter-or-setter)

Answer (score 13):

You can't make async properties and you shouldn't *want* to - properties imply *fast*, non blocking operations. If you need to perform a long running activity, as implied by you're wanting to kick of an async operation and wait for it, don't make it a property at all.

Remove the setter and make a method instead.

Comment: +1 more straight to the point. It is not supported in C#. Only methods, lambda expressions or anonymous methods can `await`

Comment: I completely agree with the point you're making. But isn't it still possible to use `Task.Wait()` in a property getter/setter?

Comment: @Domysee - possible, yes. Advisable, no.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever generally I agree with what you say about setters, but as usual, any general rule has exceptions. In this case, the MVVM pattern often requires doing async operations from setters since changing a property value of a VM object should be regarded as en Event. Getting around that often results in headaches, bugs and/or messy code when working with WPF.

Comment: Any solution for when you have a databound setter, such as a filter field and you want to kickoff loading data into a collection async?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever    I have a wpf application where ActualPageNumber property is used with databinding. So when I change the property, the setter should access the db which can be slow. That is why I wanted an async setter, to keep the gui responsive.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `async` function with property

**Alternative** Can use `Result` *Property*

```
public string UserInfo
{
    get => GetItemAsync().Result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
public bool SomeMethod
{
  get { /* some code */ }
  set
  {
    AsyncMethod().Wait();
  }
}
public async Task AsyncMethod() {}
```

[EDIT]

Comment: Great idea to use `.Wait()` :)

Comment: That `.Wait()` defeats the purpose of an `Asynchronous` methode

Comment: Even if it compiles, this approach could easily [result in a deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock).