# Possible deadlock when awaiting multiple tasks?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

According to one of the comments on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411956/can-i-use-task-result-after-task-waitall) the following code may deadlock.

```
var task1 = myFunction1Async();
var task2 = myFunction2Async();
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

Is this true?

If it is, then one of the main benefits of TPL (easily handling multiple I/O calls that may block) seems to go out of the window.

Comment: Deadlocks occur when threads that are supposed to be used for continuing after a task aren't available because they're waiting on that very same task (directly or indirectly). Whether you await one or many tasks isn't relevant -- what's relevant is how your tasks have been configured to continue (`.ConfigureAwait(false)`). If there is a deadlock already between `task1` and `task2`, this code isn't going to be in a position to solve it (but it may be able to avoid it by explicitly reconfiguring).

Comment: You already asked this. Deadlocks are caused by *blocking* and this call blocks. You haven't provided *any information* about your code so the only answer is `possibly, if the code is written in a way that allows deadlocks`. Use `await Task.WhenAny()` instead of blocking

Comment: A way *any* blocking code can cause deadlocks, is if it starts a task or thread from the UI that internally uses `.Invoke()` to update the UI, but then *blocks* with `Task.WaitAll()`, `Task.Wait()`, or by blocking on a semamphore or event. `Invoke` will try to run on the UI thread, which is blocked and thus it will never finish, thus never allowing the UI thread to proceed

Comment: If `myFunction1Async` and `myFunction2Async` are totally async, use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on every async function call, and the only use of the result is after BOTH tasks have finished, then will it still deadlock?

Comment: You can't put `ConfigureAwait` on *WaitAll*. Why those questions? Why not use the proper code? `await Task.WhenAll(...)` ? Put the reason in the question itself. Even properties can be async if handled properly -  they could return a `Lazy<T>` for example

Comment: Let `WaitAll` *rest in peace*, `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the confusion is that Task.WaitAll is the synchronous version of the (better) Task.WhenAll method. [Here's an SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123406/waitall-vs-whenall) covering the distinctions between the two.

All the comment on the referenced post was trying to say is that synchronously waiting for *many* tasks results in the same sort of deadlocks as waiting on *one* task.