# How to call async function from property setter?

Tags: asynchronous, mvvm

I have a wpf application with a `TextBox` bound to `ActualPageNumber` property in the VM. I also have a `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection` which displays the given page. The data are stored in DB.  When I change the `ActualPageNumber`, the setter accesses the db which can be slow. That is why I wanted an async setter, to keep the gui responsive.

I understand there is no async setter: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html

I also found useful stuff like https://stackoverflow.com/a/9343733/5852947, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13735418/5852947, https://nmilcoff.com/2017/07/10/stop-toggling-isbusy-with-notifytask/

Still I struggle how to go on this case. AsyncEx library can be the solution, an example would be nice.

I just would like to notify the user that the page is actually loading. If I could call async from the setter I could do it, but then I still can not use `await` in the setter because it is not `async`.

Answer (score 0):

> I also have a DataGrid bound to an ObservableCollection which displays the given page.

This is going to be the difficult part. `DataGrid` (and `DataTable` and friends) are designed with a synchronous API, and have never been updated to support asynchrony.

I'm not terribly familiar with `DataGrid`, but I'd say your options are:

1. Replace the `DataGrid` with your own custom control - say, a `ListView` that displays custom controls. Then you can display a loading spinner since you control the custom control. There are some common patterns for this like `NotifyTask`.
2. There *might* be a way to virtualize the data in the `DataGrid` in a way that it would asynchronously load. I'm not familiar enough with `DataGrid` to say whether this is actually possible, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Clearly  I think option 1 will be the answer. I will try it.

I just wonder what is the rational that in WPF a bound property setter can not be async. In my program there are several property setter which should initiate DB operation (changing the page size, changing the filter). I would be nice if I could simply use async operation in these setters and I also could await them.

Comment: @IstvanHeckl: Property setters return `void` according to the C# language specification.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** For the responsiveness of the `DataGrid`, this binding property might help: `IsAsync=True`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, IsAsync=True}"
```

also look into these DataGrid properties:

```
VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing
VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode (you'll probably need Recycling)
VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping
EnableRowVirtualization
EnableColumnVirtualization
```

But be careful, virtualization can play tricks on you. For example, I had a RowHeader (with the row number) and the values got scrambled when virtualization was on.

**2)** About the async setter for data binding: I was using a custom version of `IAsyncCommand` (see [Stephen Cleary's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-commands)).

I used the command in 2 ways: **a) binding to it from the view** (avoiding the async setter altogether) or **b) launching it from the setter** (not nice).

Example: I created an `UpdateCommand` as an `AsyncCommand` and placed everything I needed done asynchronously (like getting the values from the DB). Everything in this command is wrapped within a display+hide of a *"in progress"-like* control - in my case, a transparent cover with a spinner + "please wait...", to prevent other user actions (the "screen" is visible while the task is performed). Stripped down sample:

```
    ....
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
       UpdateCommand = AsyncCommand.Create(Update); // our own custom implementation of AsyncCommand
    }
    ....

    public AsyncCommand UpdateCommand { get; }
    internal async Task Update(object arg)
    {
        await SafeWrapWithWaitingScreenAsync(async () =>
        {
            var value = (int)arg; // or the ActualPageNumber, if used from a1)

            var data = await GetDataFromDb(value).ConfigureAwait(false);

            ...// fill in MyCollection (which is the DataGrid's ItemsSource) using the data

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyCollection));// if still needed
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    ....
    public async Task SafeWrapWithWaitingScreenAsync(Func<Task> action)
    {
        DisplayWaitingScreen = true; //Visibility of the "Waiting screen" binds to this
        try
        {
            await action().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex); // display/log ex
        }
        finally
        {
            DisplayWaitingScreen = false;
        }
    }
```

**a)** Binding to the command from the view and

***a1)*** in the command's body use `ActualPageNumber` property instead of the `arg` value

or ***a2)*** passing a `CommandParameter` which binds to the same property as `TextBox.Text` does. Example (could be missing something, couse is not the real code):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ActualPageNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ActualPageNumber}" />
         <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ActualPageNumber}" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

**b)** Not sure this is right, but before seeing [Stephen's approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding) with `NotifyTaskCompletion<TResult>` (which I will probably use in the future), for the setter, I launched the command something like:

```
private int actualPageNumber;
public int ActualPageNumber
    {
        get => actualPageNumber;
        set
        {
            actualPageNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); //the sync way

            UpdateCommand.Execute(value);
        }
    }
```